# Inner list from DTO is null while testing with Spring WebFlux

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-test

I have the following unit test (JUnit 5):

```
FluxExchangeResult<CalendarDTO> calendarEntityResult = client.get()
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .returnResult(CalendarDTO.class);

        assertNotNull(calendarEntityResult);
        final Flux<CalendarDTO> responseBody = calendarEntityResult.getResponseBody();
        responseBody.flatMap(calendarDTO -> {
            assertNotNull(calendarDTO);
            final List<AppointmentDTO> calendarEvents = calendarDTO.getCalendarEvents();
            assertNotNull(calendarEvents);
            assertFalse(calendarEvents.isEmpty());

            return Flux.just(calendarEvents);
        }).map(calendarEvents ->
            calendarEvents.get(0)
        ).doOnNext(appointmentDTO ->
            assertEquals(appointmentDTO, validAppointmentDTO())
        ).subscribe();
        /*StepVerifier.create(responseBody)
            .assertNext(calendarDTO -> {
                assertNotNull(calendarDTO);
                final List<AppointmentDTO> calendarEvents = calendarDTO.getCalendarEvents();
                assertNotNull(calendarEvents);
                assertFalse(calendarEvents.isEmpty());

                final AppointmentDTO appointmentDTO = calendarEvents.get(0);
                assertNotNull(appointmentDTO);
                assertEquals(validAppointmentDTO(), appointmentDTO);
            })
        .expectComplete()
        .verify();*/
```

For some reason, the `assertNotNull(calendarEvents);` is failing. The method itself when running it with Postman is fine. What has me puzzled is that on debug time, the `calendarEntityResult` has `calendarEvents`!

```
> GET /appointments
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]

No content

< 200 OK OK
< Content-Type: [application/json;charset=UTF-8]
< Content-Length: [377]

{"data":{"calendarEvents":[{"id":null,"startTime":"2020-01-16T13:19:37.510-06:00","endTime":"2020-01-16T14:19:37.511-06:00","timeZoneStart":"America/Regina","timeZoneEnd":"America/Regina","summary":"unit test summary","description":"unit test description","organizerName":"Developer","organizerEmail":"developer@dev.com","status":null,"alarm":15}]},"notifications":null}
```

The commented code gives the same result. To be clear, the DTO itself is not null; the problem is the calendarEvents array. It's possible I'm doing something wrong since I'm new to reactive programming in general, so code improvements are most welcome. Am I extracting the data in a wrong manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the root DTO was already wrapped into yet another DTO. It probably caused `getResponseBody()` to misinterpret the contents of the list and defaulted those to null. Leaving response here for the curious:

```
final Flux<AppointmentCalendarResponse> responseBody = client.get()
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk()
                .expectHeader().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .returnResult(AppointmentCalendarResponse.class)
                .getResponseBody();

        StepVerifier.create(responseBody)
                .assertNext(data -> {
                    CalendarDTO calendarDTO = data.getData();
                    final List<AppointmentDTO> calendarEvents = calendarDTO.getCalendarEvents();
                    assertNotNull(calendarEvents);
                })
        .expectComplete()
        .verify();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the stepverifier when asserting any type of flux. Will make your life easier.

```
    final Flux<String> responseBody = testClient.get()
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus()
            .isOk()
            .returnResult(String.class)
            .getResponseBody();

    StepVerifier.create(responseBody)
            .assertNext(s -> assertEquals(s, "Foo"))
            .assertNext(s -> assertEquals(s, "Bar"));
```

Comment: It's cleaner, but I've already tried this and gotten the same error. See the commented code above.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the same DB?

Because generaly the DB test and DB Dev is different.

Comment: It's not the same. For test we're using the embedded MongoDB from `de.flapdoodle.embed`. That wasn't the issue, though; check my answer below.